# "Перенос отклонён"

Tags: предложение, локализация, перенос-вопросов

[image: Перенос отклонён с ru.stackoverflow.com]

[Сам вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6663/login-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F)

Суть такая: вопрос был перенесен с ru.stackoverflow.com на мету, после этого закрыт (как дубликат). Плашка о том, что вопрос перенесен с другого сайта поменялась на "Перенос отклонён" (в оригинале "Migration Rejected" - судя по всему, что-то вроде "перенесенный вопрос отторгнут" ("не прижился")). В любом случае, текущий вариант перевода не очень подходит, нужно перевести как-то по-другому, плюс поправить все упоминания данного "термина".

Comment: Почему не подходит? И это всё же не дефект, а ближе к «предложению» и хорошо бы предложить своё решение, проясняющее проблему. Я пока не очень понимаю, чем «перенесенный вопрос отторгнут» лучше фразы «перенос отклонён».

Comment: Проблема скорее в механике, нежели в локализации. Тот факт, что "migration rejected" случается при одубликативании перенесённого вопроса, странно независимо от языка, на котором это написано.

Comment: @D-side вопрос по ссылке закрыт как «неясно о чем речь». Закрытые же как «дубликат» [не переносятся обратно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6691/176217).

Comment: @alexolut тогда получается, что вопрос исходит из неверной предпосылки, а все плашки на своих местах и никакой проблемы нет.

Comment: @D-side исходно он действительно [был закрыт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6663/revisions) как дубликат, но потом переоткрыт и закрыт уже с другой причиной. Видимо, всё смешалось: люди, кони...